# Converting python .py file to exe file

Tags: python, type-conversion, exe, py2exe, python-3.7

I developed a data **scraper** in PyCharm and want to convert the .py file to .exe file. I tried the various methods from StackOverflow and google but none of those worked for me. Can someone please help me with this error?

I am using py2exe for conversion. Other solution didn't work for me, maybe because of PyCharm. The PyCharm window pops open instead of command prompt unlike other guides available online.

```
directory> python setup.py py2exe
\\Run\\
Running py2exe
```

The error says there is no command supplied.
In CommandPrompt it says:

```
yield "store", (name[oparg];)
IndexError: Tuple index out of range.
```

Comment: Does your python code actually runs in pycharm?

Comment: Yes, I was able to run my code and get the data but I need to convert this to .exe file now for data analyst team.

Comment: `yield "store", (name[oparg];)` looks like coming from your code, can you share your code as well

Comment: I don't think it is from the code as I can't even successfully convert Hello world file from .py to .exe

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578808/python-indexerror-tuple-index-out-of-range-when-using-py2exe) seems like you need to use cxfreeze or pyinstaller

Comment: The py2exe doesn't support any version above python 3.4. I will cxfreeze for now. Do you have any other recommendation?

Comment: No I don't sorry, I don't have much experience with these

Comment: @swapnilindahood: Definitely try `cx_freeze`, i have used it successfully amogst all the options available. Try it with your hello world example. Also, if this works and Pycharm in your Pycharm doesn't then use it with Python not with any IDE like Anaconda etc.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal I tried using cx_freeze and it asked me to download Microsoft Visual C++ 2014. I installed it but it is still prompting me with the same error/message.

Comment: A while ago I posted the script I use for `PyInstaller` if you decide to give it a try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54792467/4777984